# click on psedu element of ::before and send keys in it

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to click on Select Size element, but the following line is not working

```
WebElement webElement= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".product-option-label"))
webElement.click()
```

here is the Elements
[image]

how can I click on Select size?
Another question is, for the following question, how can I send keys of the following input fields?
[image]

Answer (score -1):

[python]  substitute [java]
It`s very siple than you think!
api - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#card_input_2')))
or
self.WebElement.find_element_by_id('#card_input_2').click()
or
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#card_input_2'))).click()
```

Comment: It is not working when ": : before " type of pseudo element is there

Comment: try it WebElement webElement= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#.product-option-label")).click()

Comment: Please don't answer if you don't know about it, this simple cssSelector will not work for pseudo element